# Not able to start tomcat 7.0 on my server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat, unix, tomcat7

I am not able to start my tomcat (7.0) on my server. While starting it is giving below error message.

```
 FAIL,Resource start failed [Context: Failure Reason=PID not found;Code=SCLD-LRM-4022;
```

I don't know why it is searching PID before . My understanding is that while starting tomcat PID should be assigned to it. Let me know what can I do to get through this.

Current status of tomcat is.

```
FAIL,NumRunning/MinConfigured[0/1]
```

I have tried to stop it and restart again but no luck. While stopping below message I am getting.

```
INFO,Resource is not running [Context: Code=SCLD-LRM-1040;]
```

I have tried  "ps -ef|grep Java" and I can see one PID running for tomcat after start

```
tomcat    55803  55804 99 05:23 ?        00:00:17 java -Dlrmiid=LRMIID-222380 -DlrmRName=org.apache.tomcat
```

but in status it is showing fail. Can anyone guide me here?

Thanks,
Anshu

Answer (score 0):

Seems JNDI name is not on the correct place as it should be inside Resource element but it's instead in Context one.

Or check context.xml file read permission.

Comment: Hi Abbas,

Thanks for reply. I have checked permission of context.xml file. Permission is not an issue not sure about other solution that you have given. If you can elaborate the issue then it will be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

can you share more about your resource configuration like .

define a data source that is shared across all Tomcat applications, or define a data source specifically for one application.

Example: